# Next Button is in disabled even mandatory dropdown is selected by selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, dropdown

I am doing automation for the application using selenium, I have a scenario in which I need to fill the drop-down mandatory. I am filling the drop-down value using below code which is working fine:

List allOptions = driver.findElements(By.xpath(properties.getProperty("test")));
System.out.println(allOptions.size());

```
    for(int i = 0; i<=allOptions.size()-1; i++) {
         
         
        if(allOptions.get(i).getText().contains("Won")) {
             
            allOptions.get(i).click();
            break;
    
    
    
        }
    }
```

Now the problem is when I check for the Next button it is in disabled.

But when I select the drop-down value manually Next button is enabled and it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement selectstage2 = driver.findElement(By. xpath(properties.getProperty("test")));  
selectstage2.sendKeys("type");
  Actions keyDown2 = new Actions(driver);
  keyDown2.sendKeys(Keys. Chord(Keys.DOWN)).perform();
```